# Is it possible trigger an ios/android app to start when a connection with a known bluetooth device is detected?

Tags: android, ios, swift, bluetooth

I would like to write an app (eventually for both Android and iOS in Swift) that will automatically start up when the phone connects with a designated bluetooth device(s). Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Add these filters with your broad cast receiver :

```
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

ACL_CONNECTED signals when bluetooth is connected and ACL_DISCONNECTED signals bluetooth disconnection

For specific device you have to check intents/context in broadcast receiver

Two permission you need to add are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: Is there an iOS version of this?